# Best practice: A child node's knowledge about its parent

Tags: oop, tree, parent-child

I wanted to get an idea of the best practice for how much information a child node in a tree should know about its parent.

My current problem is fairly simple and straight-forward. I have a tree of information and wanted a to get the "full name" of a leaf node (in this case it will be the name of each node in the tree to the leaf node separated by a dot). I can do this either by adding a "getFullName" method to the leaf nodes which traverses up the tree to the root and prepends each parent's name and returns the final result but this would require the leaf nodes knowing the class type of its parent (leaf and non-leaf are not the same class). Or I can add a utility function somewhere else that does basically the same thing but knows about the different class types.

I attempted to search around but the question is a little too broad to get any useful hits on Google.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *do* have a lot of options here, and yes your question addresses the common situation of trading off processing efficiency on the one hand with increased storage requirements and possible redundancy on the other.

There is no single best practice.  The space/time tradeoff depends on your situation.  If you go with redundant storage, keeping both child and parent links within nodes, you will need to make sure your data structure is properly encapsulated and your methods keep everything consistent.

Since you have a use case that does traverse to nodes from the top, parent links work fine and you can compose the full name via recursion or building a string from back to front.  Because the use case is for your situation, it is not a bad idea.

Another option is to store the full name in the node, but that adds redundancy in case you move nodes.

In short, you don't have to worry about violating best practices, but you should weigh all choices in making the choice that is right for you.

Now if you were making a general-purpose tree data structure, such as Java's TreeNode, you would probably create an interface and allow people to implement things as they see fit, providing a suitable general implementation (DefaultMutableTreeNode) that has all links -- parent, child, and sibling.

Answer (score 1):

The case you depict is a typical case for use of recursion. In other words, each node in your tree could have a method called `getFullName` defined in this way:

```
string getFullName() {
    myFullName = myParent.getFullName() + myLocalName;
    return myFullName;
}
```

(this is pseudo-code; I assume that if `myParent` is nil, then `myParent.getFullName()` is the empty string, you can change things as appropriate to your specific language)

Recursion ends when there is no parent. The only things that a node must know is its own name and who its parent is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with having the child-node class "know" about its parents. The parents can implement an interface if you're worried about extensibility.

Another alternative is to have parent classes update a "name" field of all child-nodes in their subtree... might make sense if you make a big tree and then just query it (constant-time lookup). Again, interfaces can help if you're worried about too much coupling.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least each node should know it's parent.  Leaf and non-Leaf nodes have different classes, but that means every parent is of the same class.  Use this to traverse up the tree and build the name (in reverse) as you go.